# Converting a big byte array to a natural in a double variable

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger

I have a sequence of byte arrays of size 8 (64 bits). I want to put the corresponding natural number into a variable (of primitive type), for this reason i thought to use a double variable because the other primitive types do not support a so high range (from 0 to 2^64).

I show an example:

I have the following array of bytes

```
000000 0000000 0000000 0000000 0000000 0000000 0000000 0000010
```

the corresponding natural number is 2.

I have tried this:

```
double bigNaturalNum = new BigInteger(byteArray).doubleValue();
```

There problem is that the doubleValue() method returns the double value that the byte represents, thus the resulting value can be a decimal value.

Comment: Perhaps you want `long`  (64-bit integer), rather than `double` (double-precision floating-point)?

Comment: Well, you gotta accept the fact that 2^64 can't be represented accurately by any of the primitives. That's what `BigInteger` is for. Do you want an `long` for when the number is within the range of `long`, and a `double` for when it exceeds the range?

Comment: Further to the other comments, `long` is 64-bit signed. There are no suitable unsigned primitives in Java (only the weird 16-bit `char`). So you need an object, or treat `long` as if it were unsigned knowing that it is signed.

Comment: If I store the number in a double variable and the value is natural, why I can not represent a 64 bit value?

Comment: *If I store the number in a double variable and the value is natural, why I can not represent a 64 bit value?*. Because you can't fit 64 bits into a 53-bit field. See [double format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Answer (score 1):

This depends if the most significant bit in the `byte[]` is used as the sign bit e.g. [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). If so you can map `byte[]` to `long` with `ByteBuffer`:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[] { (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff };
long l = ByteBuffer.wrap(arr).getLong();
System.out.println(l); // -1
System.out.println(Long.toHexString(l)); // ffffffffffffffff
```

If not you should use `BigInteger` with `signum=1` to indicate that you don't use sign bit:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[] { (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff };
BigInteger i = new BigInteger(1, arr);
System.out.println(i); // 18446744073709551615
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved storing the value in a `long` variable. Java has not an unsigned long primitive type but from JavaSE 8, you can treat the long variable as an unsigned long variable through the methods of class Long [Long - JavaSE 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html).

You can use for instance the method `public static int compareUnsigned(long x, long y)` which

> Compares two long values numerically treating the values as unsigned.

In this way you can store 2^64 natural nubers in a long variable.